# Why does std::memory_order_acq_rel always trigger warnings in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, standards, memory-barriers

My compiler is clang 18.1.0-rc1; and the following code triggers two warnings:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> n;

int main() {
    // Warning: Memory order argument to atomic operation is invalid
    n.load(std::memory_order_acq_rel); 

    // Warning: Memory order argument to atomic operation is invalid
    n.store(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
}
```

**What's the legal usage of** `std::memory_order_acq_rel`**?**

---

**Update**

```
n.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel); // now is ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's valid with RMWs like `fetch_add` that both load and store in one operation.

The acquire part of `acq_rel` is valid for the load side, the release part is valid for the store side.

Comment: I would even add: if you aren't using *some* RMWs on your atomics, you're almost certainly doing it wrong. While load/store are sometimes used as an extra thing before/after an RMW, the only case I can think of for *only* using load/store is a simple killswitch.

Comment: @o11c: Another case is a value written by only one thread, read by one or more other threads.  With only one writer, it's safe (and more efficient) to do `foo.store(foo.load(relaxed)+1, release)`.  A single-producer single-consumer lock-free queue ring buffer can be build out of just loads + stores, IIRC.

Comment: Or an SPMC queue where the write_idx is only updated by the writer without atomic RMWs, but the read_idx does need an atomic RMW (like CAS_weak).

Answer (score 2):

It warns you about undefined behaviors in your code.

[`std::atomic<T>::load`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load): *If `order` is one of `std::memory_order_release` and `std::memory_order_acq_rel`, the behavior is undefined.*

[`std::atomic<T>::store`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/store): *If `order` is one of `std::memory_order_consume`, `std::memory_order_acquire` and `std::memory_order_acq_rel`, the behavior is undefined.*

The valid operations for `std::memory_order_acq_rel` are `std::atomic<T>::fetch_add`, `std::atomic<T>::exchange()` and the other read-modify-write operations.